# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

So I am trying to use the Flask-Login together with my registered Flask blueprint. I've already installed the flask-login extension, initialized the extension in my main.py file and it showed up whenever I used my bin folder or used the command 'pip freeze'. However, whenever I tried to import it into my code, I get the titled error.

Here is the code snippet that is causing me trouble:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from importlib import import_module
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager #This line's the problem

def apply_themes(app):
    @app.context_processor
    def override_url_for():
        return dict(url_for=_generate_url_for_theme)

    def _generate_url_for_theme(endpoint, **values):
        if endpoint.endswith("static"):
            themename = values.get("theme", None) or app.config.get(
                "DEFAULT_THEME", None
            )
            if themename:
                theme_file = "{}/{}".format(themename, values.get("filename", ""))
                if path.isfile(path.join(app.static_folder, theme_file)):
                    values["filename"] = theme_file
        return url_for(endpoint, **values)


    def register_blueprints(app):
        lstModule = ["base"]
        for item in lstModule:
        module = import_module("app.{}.routes".format(item))
        app.register_blueprint(module.blueprint)


    def create_app(config):
        app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="base/static")
        app.config.from_object(config)
        register_blueprints(app)
        apply_themes(app)
        login_manager = LoginManager()
        login_manager.init_app(app)
        return app
```

Here is my main.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from app import create_app
from config import config_dict

try:
    config_mode = config_dict["Debug"]
except KeyError:
    exit("Error: Invalid CONFIG_MODE environment variable entry.")
app = create_app(config_mode)
app.secret_key = "super secret key"
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port="5001", threaded=True)
```

Comment: Are you running this in an IDE?  The usual cause of this kind of problem is that you have multiple installations of Python, and you're not using the one you expect.

Comment: I'm running this in VS Code. How do I check if I have multiple installation of python?

Comment: You can do `import sys` / `print(sys.version)`.  You can configure VSCode to use the one you want.

Comment: 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

I don't see anything wrong with this one.

Comment: The KEY is, is that the same version you get in a command line, where you ran pip?  Do `python -V` in a command line (not inside VSCode) and see what that says.

Comment: I opened my command prompt and ran this line, it still gave me python 3.9.13. I did look for python file in my laptop with everything, and there seems to be python 3.11, 3.8 folders lying around. I will give an update after I delete everything

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using VSCode. I just had the wrong interpreter for the current workspace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).